# Ubuntu installer can't see Mac HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I've been trying to set up an Ubuntu 16.04 partition on my MacBook Pro (2017). I've created a 100GB partition for it (diskutil below). However when I try to install Ubuntu from my USB disk image, the installer can only detect the USB hard drive - it can't see the internal drive. Same problem arises if I try fdisk -l. Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

```
 /dev/disk0 (internal):
 #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
 0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
 1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
 2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         150.0 GB   disk0s2
 3:       Microsoft Basic Data UbuntuPart              100.0 GB   disk0s3

 /dev/disk1 (synthesized):
 #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
 0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +150.0 GB   disk1
                          Physical Store disk0s2
 1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            108.2 GB   disk1s1
 2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.3 MB    disk1s2
 3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.8 MB   disk1s3
 4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s5

 /dev/disk2 (external, physical):
 #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
 0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *16.0 GB    disk2
 1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
 2:       Microsoft Basic Data UBUNTU                  15.8 GB    disk2s2


 [X:~]$ diskutil info /dev/disk0s3
    Device Identifier:        disk0s3
    Device Node:              /dev/disk0s3
    Whole:                    No
    Part of Whole:            disk0

    Volume Name:              UbuntuPart
    Mounted:                  Yes
    Mount Point:              /Volumes/UbuntuPart

    Partition Type:           Microsoft Basic Data
    File System Personality:  ExFAT
    Type (Bundle):            exfat
    Name (User Visible):      ExFAT

    OS Can Be Installed:      No
    Media Type:               Generic
    Protocol:                 PCI-Express
    SMART Status:             Not Supported
    Volume UUID:              D571AF1C-6074-3F47-AF60-B2987240331B
    Disk / Partition UUID:    036C0F0D-3771-4562-A55F-67642719B407

    Disk Size:                100.0 GB (99998498816 Bytes) (exactly 195309568 512-Byte-Units)
    Device Block Size:        4096 Bytes

    Volume Total Space:       100.0 GB (99994304512 Bytes) (exactly 195301376 512-Byte-Units)
    Volume Used Space:        9.6 MB (9568256 Bytes) (exactly 18688 512-Byte-Units) (0.0%)
    Volume Available Space:   100.0 GB (99984736256 Bytes) (exactly 195282688 512-Byte-Units) (100.0%)
    Allocation Block Size:    131072 Bytes

    Read-Only Media:          No
    Read-Only Volume:         No

    Device Location:          Internal
    Removable Media:          Fixed

    Solid State:              Yes
```

Comment: Hey did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Did anyone ever solve this? Having the same problem...

Comment: has anyone solved this?

Comment: I have this same problem: I partitioned my macbook HDD using disk utilitiy and created a 117GB FAT32 partition. Ubuntu live CD can't see either partition. It simply tries to use the USB drive as the installation target complains there isn't enough room.

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally figured this out...

The NVMe storage used in the newer MacBooks isn't supported in the versions of the Linux kernel currently used in most distributions. This support wasn't added [until kernel version 5.1.5](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux/issues/71#issuecomment-507325112), which won't be packaged with Ubuntu until version 19.10 (currently in beta using kernel version 5.2.0).

Right now the options seem to be:

- Make your own bootable image of your distro of choice using a kernel version of 5.1.5 or higher
- Used a pre-patched version of a distro ([example](https://github.com/mikeeq/mbp-fedora))
- Wait for 19.10

Comment: Suggestion: This part, "the newer MacBooks" should mention which year models are applicable--whether this is also applicable to OP (MacBook Pro 2017)? In fact, the linked project on GitHub has [NVMe section in README](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux/blob/master/README.md#nvme) that mentioned "works out of box" for MacBook Pro 13 and 14 series, which makes the compatibility issue confusing overall.

Comment: So now that 19.10 is available, I haven't had any luck with it. Was this support pushed back or something?